# Granting permissions to workflows SharePoint 2016 - Your tenant administrator has to approve this app

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, designer-workflow, 2016, app-permissions

I am trying to grant workflows permissions to user profiles, in order to use User Profiles properties in SharePoint Designer workflows 2013 mode. I am following the steps here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/get-user-profile-properties-data-in-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/

But when I am trying to grand the permissions I get this message: "Your tenant administrator has to approve this app."

[image]

I am in the farm admins group, and I modified the user profile service application permissions to add my account to have full control.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using the windows authentications or ADFS?

Comment: I am using windows authentication.

Comment: have you tried to login with actual farm admin account (which run the SharePoint timer service)? we had issue in past and we use the actual farm admin account.

Comment: Farm account (System account) cannot grant permissions for apps, it's a security limitation in SharePoint server, it has to be a service account assigned as farm admin and local admin.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **On-Premise SharePoint 2019** and got the same error when adding an app.

The issue got solved by using Central Administration URL with suffix `_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`, so in my case this syntax works `http://HOSTNAME:PORT/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`.

With **SharePoint Online** one could use `-admin` suffix in the first part of hostname, like `https://[mytenant]-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`. It's used instead of `https://[mytenant].sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure must be completed by a user that has Site Owner permissions.

You could refer to this article for more:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo

Comment: I am already a site collection admin of the site and already exist in the site owners group.

Comment: Have you tried to do this with another user account with site owners permissions？